# Change --push-option with local hooks

Tags: git, hook

Is it possible to change the --push-option with local hook when I make a push?

Example: When I run the command `git push origin master`, the pre-push local hook inject the value "test" to the --push-option, changing the git command to `git push origin master --push-option "test"`

The main objective is that I need to make some validations before push the changes, then, I will generate a token and inject it to the push-option, and in the server side hook, I will check if the validation were made or not through the token.

Comment: No: by the time the pre-push hook runs, it's too late. To handle this, don't run `git push` directly: run your own script that generates the token, then have the *script* run `git push`.